# RMAN error during auxillary backup

Tags: oracle, rman

I am getting ORA error while doing Auxillary cloning for database from two different server using RMAN backup while using below command:-

```
duplicate database to "HFSDBRED" backup location '/orabackup/RMAN/HFSDBRED_BKP' nofilenamecheck set DB_FILE_NAME_CONVERT=('/oradata/HFSDBPRD/datafile','/oradata/HFSDBRED/datafile') set LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT=('/oradata/HFSDBPRD/onlinelog','/oradata/HFSDBRED/onlinelog','/optware/oracle/HFSDBPRD/onlinelog','/optware/oracle/HFSDBRED/onlinelog');
```

Error:-

```
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
RMAN-01009: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one of: "backup, db_file_name_convert, device, dorecover, force, from, high, logfile, nofilenamecheck, noredo, noresume, open, password, pfile, skip readonly, skip, spfile, tablespace, to restore point, undo, until restore point, until, ;"
RMAN-01008: the bad identifier was: LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT
RMAN-01007: at line 3 column 1 file: standard input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `DB` & `LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT` values *`without paranthesis`*, as follows :

```
set DB_FILE_NAME_CONVERT='/oradata/HFSDBPRD/datafile','/oradata/HFSDBRED/datafile'
set LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT='/oradata/HFSDBPRD/onlinelog','/oradata/HFSDBRED/onlinelog','/optware/oracle/HFSDBPRD/onlinelog','/optware/oracle/HFSDBRED/onlinelog'
```